# incorporating my html-css design into ruby on rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have created a web page template using html,bootstrap and css. Now, I have to see it run in my rails application. Can anyone help me by telling the way to do it step by step? What all things have to be done from the beginning for the same?
Please help!

Comment: You should follow a tutorial about how to create a ruby on rails app to learn all the basics. To render a view, short version: you should have at least a controller with an action, a route for your action and an html file with the action name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really follow a [tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book) about how to create a ruby on rails app to learn all the basics.

Short version: you need

- a controller with an action
- a route for your action
- a html file with the action name
- a scss file with your stylesheet

A real basic version of what it could looks like :

**config/routes.rb**

```
root :to => "static_pages#home"
```

**app/controller/static_pages_controller.rb**

```
class StaticPagesController < ActionController::Base
  def home
  end
end
```

**app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb**

```
Hello World
```

**app/views/layout/application.html.erb**:
Let the default (it wraps your home.html.erb file and include your application stylesheet)

**app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss**: It requires your other stylesheets

```
//= require home
```

**app/assets/stylesheets/home.scss**

```
Puts your style in it
```

Comment: okay. I have created a pages controller and now, the homepage is displayed. But, I have folders like css,fonts,images and js in my design. where should i put these folders?

Comment: You should put it in your assets folder, but not just as it is. You should insert your css stylesheet as I said. For the fonts, you should create a folder in assets. For your images you have the choice to store them in image folder in assets (better) or public folder. Js files should go in specific folder in assets. As I told you, you should take at least half an hour to take a look at tutorials which will explain you everything with a lot more details.